# How do I create a wrapper around a Tensor class from Eigen?

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

There is this class here for tensors in Eigen:

https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/default/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/README.md?fileviewer=file-view-default

I would like to create a wrapper class around it so that I can specify in the constructor the rank of the tensor, and it will dynamically create a tensor of that rank.

However, the rank of the tensor in the eigen class is specified through a template variable. `Tensor<double, 5>` would give rank 5, for example.

How do I create a class such as

```
class Tensor2 {
Tensor<double,??>* myTensor; // what to do here?
public:
Tensor2(int rank)
{
myTensor = new Tensor<double,rank>();
}
```

Comment: The rank is a compile-time constant (specified as a template parameter) and thus cannot be passed as an argument to the constructor of your wrapper - if you need to create arbitrary rank tensors then you'll require some sort of factory pattern to create `Tensor` objects with given ranks.

Comment: However, if `Tensor2` is intended to just be a rank-2 tensor then you can simply declare the `myTensor` field as `Tensor<double, 2> myTensor;`.

Comment: Are you sure there exists no argument constructor for tensor?